# Is it possible to use color variables in the Visual Studio Code when creating themes and syntax colors

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, color-scheme

#### Explanation:

While i created **Color Themes** in **Sublime Text**, there was a possibility to use color variables instead values.

It's very useful when you have a lot of colors. I mean like this:

[image]

#### Question:

Is it possible to use color variables in the Visual Studio Code somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I think VS Code, currently does not support any of these `hsl`, `rgb` and `rgba`.

It only support `hex` values.